# expo issue when building for ios with many sound files

Tags: react-native, expo

I am running `expo build:ios / android` 
I have 423mb of data split across about 80 sound files. The biggest file is 30mb. When uploading the files i get an error message.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 413
    at createError (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\xdl\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\xdl\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\xdl\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:236:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I checked ios size requirements and saw that it was 4gb for the ipa. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give us a code to reproduce this error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, im running 'expo build:ios'